# What FAA requirements exist for electronic ignition systems on piston engines?

Tags: faa-regulations, piston-engine

Most GA piston aircraft still use dual magnetos for their ignition system, but there are some [STC kits available to add electronic ignition to common piston engines](http://www.electroair.net/stc_ignition_kit.html), and new aircraft often come with [FADEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FADEC) systems.

Are there particular FAA requirements for electronic ignition systems?

If so, what are they and how can you demonstrate compliance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ignition requirements are pretty straight-forward:

> [**§23.1165   Engine ignition systems.**](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:1.0.1.3.10#14:1.0.1.3.10.5.97.75)
>
> (a) Each battery ignition system must be supplemented by a generator
>   that is automatically available as an alternate source of electrical
>   energy to allow continued engine operation if any battery becomes
>   depleted.
>
> (b) The capacity of batteries and generators must be large enough to
>   meet the simultaneous demands of the engine ignition system and the
>   greatest demands of any electrical system components that draw from
>   the same source.
>
> (c) The design of the engine ignition system must account for—
>
> (1) The condition of an inoperative generator;
>
> (2) The condition of a completely depleted battery with the generator
>   running at its normal operating speed; and
>
> (3) The condition of a completely depleted battery with the generator
>   operating at idling speed, if there is only one battery.
>
> (d) There must be means to warn appropriate crewmembers if
>   malfunctioning of any part of the electrical system is causing the
>   continuous discharge of any battery used for engine ignition.
>
> (e) Each turbine engine ignition system must be independent of any
>   electrical circuit that is not used for assisting, controlling, or
>   analyzing the operation of that system.
>
> (f) In addition, for commuter category airplanes, each turbine engine
>   ignition system must be an essential electrical load.

Comment: What about aircraft not certified under Part 23?

Comment: @egid His question is about "GA piston aircraft" so I doubt that many of them would be certified under anything else.  :)

Comment: There are a ton of GA piston designs certified under CAR part 3, both before and after 1965 when Part 23 was created.

Comment: @egid *I know nothing about CAR*....  ;-)

Comment: I think we can consider CAR 3 and FAR 23 "roughly equivalent" for these purposes (I'm fairly certain the FAA would view any modifications/retrofits in the context of FAR 23, even if the original type certificate was issued under CAR 3).